# How to make this TypeScript code DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)?

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings

Below is a snippit of some TypeScript code lifted from a Redux reducer I'm working on. It works, but it is sure verbose. There's got to be a better way to do this, right?

```
  switch (iterationNum) {
    case 1:
      state.iteration1Result = action.payload;
      break;
    case 2:
      state.iteration2Result = action.payload;
      break;
    case 3:
      state.iteration3Result = action.payload;
      break;
    case 4:
      state.iteration4Result = action.payload;
      break;
    case 5:
      state.iteration5Result = action.payload;
      break;
    case 6:
      state.iteration6Result = action.payload;
      break;
    case 7:
      state.iteration7Result = action.payload;
      break;
    case 8:
      state.iteration8Result = action.payload;
      break;
  }
```

Here's the definition of state:

```
interface InitialState {
  iteration1Result: IterationResult;
  iteration2Result: IterationResult;
  iteration3Result: IterationResult;
  ..., etc.
}
```

I naively hoped I could do something like this

```
state[`iteration${iterationNum}result`] = action.payload;
```

But I get this error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '`iteration${number}Result`' can't be used to index type 'WritableDraft<TestStartActivity>'.ts(7053)
```

Comment: You should not have `iteration1Result` etc properties to begin with. Use an array instead.

Comment: My data scientist is requesting these field names. This gets kicked to JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `switch`, use the `iterationNum` to use bracket notation to come up with the property to assign to. Construct the property name with a template literal so that TypeScript can interpret it correctly.

Assuming that `iterationNum` is `1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8`, you can do

```
state[`iteration${iterationNum}Result`] = action.payload;
```

If you have to narrow `iterationNum` first... in JavaScript, you'd use `.includes` to check, but that's [not really possible in a neat way in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26255) (due to a behavior that's arguably a bug). Either do

```
if (iterationNum === 1 || iterationNum === 2 // etc
```

or

```
const nums = [1, 2, 3] as const; // etc
type Num = (typeof nums)[number];
if (nums.includes(iterationNum as Num)) {
    state[`iteration${iterationNum as Num}Result`] = action.payload;
}
```

Comment: Complementing, you can also use `Record<\`iteration${T}Result\`, IterationResult>` to create the InitialState type, where `T` equals to `1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8`.

Comment: state[`iteration${iterationNum as Num}Result`] yields an error similar to the one I gave in my question: ts(7053)

Comment: @JayKoutavas Sounds like your `Num` is `number`, and not `1 | 2 | 3` etc. Use the approach in my answer so that `Num` will alias the union instead of `number`.

Comment: @enzo, could you expand on your answer? How does the definition of `InitialState` look with this approach?

Comment: @JayKoutavas I've created a sample [here](http://shorturl.at/ovyCX).

Comment: @JayKoutavas Did you forget to use the `as const` that my answer uses?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I did add the `as const`. I also now made my iterationNum of type Num. Still getting that pesky TS7053 error, though the code runs great.

Comment: @JayKoutavas I can't reproduce. It works fine in the TS playground. Double check that your code matches mine.

Comment: I even did this for grins: `type Num = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8;`

Comment: @CertainPerformance My actual code is a bit more involved. (I simplified state for sake of example.) That may be a factor.

Comment: @JayKoutavas See this link for a working demo https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEYD2A7AzgF3gMyUgXPAN4BQ88AlhiDFBhagIwBKIaArhBoZjBSgHMA3GUrVa9VACZWHLjwx9BI8lRp0GKAMyzO3eL37CSAXxIlQkWAmTosaiZoBy7ALaEUbgEY0RtzPCermjwALzwANqMADTwUrFaALrwUCH+GCIYAJ4ADggurmHwABTZeUjYgW5oAJQRQT4wiSIUlcVBaAB0-JDsoGjFDhqoBSkhBTU1xKLkuEgRAAZDkigAJETLzm5j8AUmulwLyeEA5FBeYCciZkA

Comment: @CertainPerformance, I copied your code into my project. Got a TS7053 error on that too. Using `tsc && yarn lint`

Comment: @JayKoutavas Well, as you can see from TypeScript's official IDE, no such problem appears to arise...